# g++ not detected on Linux EC2 instance

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-ec2, theano

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

This happened after I successfully installed gcc.

How do I add gcc to the path of a remote machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type

```
which g++
```

do you get the location of the file?
It is usually installed in **/usr/bin/** directory which is in the default path for all users